# Reattache a volume on a EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I can not attach back a volume to an instance.
Already try to name it /dev/xvda, /dev/sda1 or /dev/sda(don't even attach) but when looking to instance status the volume don't apear at Root device, but on Block devices..

the instance: i-037681c5cce05ec5d

the volume: vol-07d60c2e66bcf2a36

When I try to start the instance this error appear:

Invalid value 'i-037681c5cce05ec5d' for instanceId. Instance does not have a volume attached at root (xvda)

Root device -

Block devices  /dev/xvda

or

Block devices /dev/sda1

[instance proprieties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L06QP.png)

neither works

Comment: I have exactly same question. Did you resolve this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and it is you are using **/dev/xvda** when attaching the volume again.
Instead. You must use **xvda** alone. It solves the problem.